# How to perform mysql functions in Yii2 query?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I'm always getting syntax errors when I'm trying to perform mysql functions in my Yii2 query.

What I need to do is select a third column `updated_at` and do the mysql function, which is written in the variable

Here's the code:

```
        $contractExpiryDate = 'DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(updated_at), '
        . 'INTERVAL term_months MONTH) AS contract_expiry_date';

    $query = self::find()
        ->select([
            self::tableName() . '.*',
            Client::tableName() . '.company_name AS company_name',
            ClientService::tableName() . '.agreement_no AS agreement_no',
            ClientService::tableName() . $contractExpiryDate,
        ])->joinWith('client')
          ->joinWith('loans')
          ->orderBy('company_name');
```

Error message:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AS contract_expiry_date FROM `client_profit_loss_report` LEFT JOIN `client` ON' at line 1
>   The SQL being executed was: SELECT `client_profit_loss_report`.*, `client`.`company_name` AS `company_name`, `client_service`.`agreement_no` AS `agreement_no`, client_serviceDATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(updated_at), INTERVAL term_months MONTH) AS contract_expiry_date FROM `client_profit_loss_report` LEFT JOIN `client` ON `client_profit_loss_report`.`client_id` = `client`.`id` LEFT JOIN `client_profit_loss_report_loan` ON `client_profit_loss_report`.`id` = `client_profit_loss_report_loan`.`report_id` LEFT JOIN `client_service` ON `client_profit_loss_report_loan`.`client_service_id` = `client_service`.`id` ORDER BY `company_name`

Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is anything going wrong (errors showing or being logged)?

Comment: I've updated my question with the error

Comment: @HELPME I have updated my answer. Try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about to which table each column goes, but try this...

```
$contractExpiryDate = 'DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME('. ClientService::tableName() .'.updated_at), '
    . 'INTERVAL '. ClientService::tableName() .'.term_months MONTH) AS contract_expiry_date';

$query = self::find()
    ->select([
        self::tableName() . '.*',
        Client::tableName() . '.company_name AS company_name',
        ClientService::tableName() . '.agreement_no AS agreement_no',
        $contractExpiryDate,
    ])->joinWith('client')
      ->joinWith('loans')
      ->orderBy('company_name');
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be the code that works for you. You need to reference the table name on each field:

```
$query = self::find()
    ->select([
        self::tableName() . '.*',
        Client::tableName() . '.company_name AS company_name',
        ClientService::tableName() . '.agreement_no AS agreement_no',
        'DATE_ADD(
            FROM_UNIXTIME(' . ClientService::tableName() . '.updated_at),
            INTERVAL ' . ClientService::tableName() . '.term_months MONTH
        ) AS contract_expiry_date',
    ])->joinWith('client')
    ->joinWith('loans')
    ->orderBy('company_name');
```

If you wish to format the date as per you other comment, you simply need to wrap `DATE_ADD` function call in a `DATE_FORMAT` function call, like so:

```
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD('2017-09-07', INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m-%d');
```

So with your query, like this:

```
$query = self::find()
    ->select([
        self::tableName() . '.*',
        Client::tableName() . '.company_name AS company_name',
        ClientService::tableName() . '.agreement_no AS agreement_no',
        'DATE_FORMAT(
            DATE_ADD(
                FROM_UNIXTIME(' . ClientService::tableName() . '.updated_at),
                INTERVAL ' . ClientService::tableName() . '.term_months MONTH
            ),
            '%Y-%m-%d'
        ) AS contract_expiry_date',
    ])->joinWith('client')
    ->joinWith('loans')
    ->orderBy('company_name');
```

Comment: I have just taken a longer look at this. I cannot advise precisely on the solution without information on your database schema. Are the `updated_at` and `term_months` fields in the `client_service` table?